# Laravel 5.4 - Make view login error

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to do a controller for my site in this way

```
class MyController extends BaseController {

public function login()
{   
    $this->layout->testata = View::make('OUT');
    $this->layout->content = View::make('auth.login');
}
```

but Laravel says "Attempt to assign property of non-object".
What's the problem?

Basecontroller has only the contructor

```
class BaseController extends Controller {

    public $layout = 'a.main';
    protected function setupLayout()
    {
        if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
        {
            $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
        }
    }

}
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Your class isn't assigning layout so when you try to set properties they don't exist. Create your own setupLayout function or maybe inherit from BaseController instead of Controller.

Comment: `$layout` is defined to be a string in the BaseController, but it's being referred to as an object in the login function. Furthermore, since MyController doesn't extend BaseController, `$layout` isn't even available in MyController.

Comment: I made an error with copy-paste. is class MyController extends BaseController { But doesn't work the same

Answer (score 1):

In your BaseController, you have a property named as `$layout` and its default value is `a.main` which is a string.

In your `login` method of `MyController` class you are setting the `testata` and `content` property of `$layout` property. But what that `$layout` property is holding? Its holding a string `a.main`. That string is not object that has neither `testata` property nor `content` property. That's why you are getting this error.

Now, you can claim that you are setting up that `$layout` property to an object in your `setupLayout` method of `BaseController`. But the question is, when the `setupLayout` is being called? There is no signed that the `$layout` property is holding any object without the initial default value `a.main`.

As a quick fix, you can call your `setupLayout` method in the constructor of the `BaseController` so that the `$layout` property will be set up while the `BaseController` will be initiated. Something as below:

```
class BaseController extends Controller {

    public $layout = 'a.main';

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setupLayout();
    }

    protected function setupLayout()
    {
        if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
        {
            $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
        }
    }
}
```

Besides, To solve the you should add initialize the `$layout` variable to an object `stdClass(Standard class of PHP)` so that `$layout` property is no more an `non-object`. Then you can set your `testata` and `content`.

```
$this->layout = new \stdClass; //or new stdClass();
$this->layout->testata = View::make('OUT');
$this->layout->content = View::make('auth.login');
```

Comment: Thank you, but if I add the function __construct() I've the same problem

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Answer edited. check it out and please let me know.

Comment: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\stdClass' not found

Comment: `$this->layout = new \stdClass;` Isn't namespacing fun?

Comment: As @ChrisForrence said, add a `\` before `stdClass` so that `PHP` do try to look for it in the current namespace but in the `PHP` root namespace.

Comment: @Chris Forrence "$this->layout = new \stdClass; Isn't namespacing fun?" nO "In your login method of MyController class you are setting the testata and content property of $layout property. But what that $layout property is holding? Its holding a string a.main. That string is not object that has neither testata property nor content property. That's why you are getting this error." -> it makes me mad. "$this->layout->content = View::make('auth.login');" -> works xfectly. Thank u